# Fastify Typescript request query

Tags: node.js, typescript, fastify

I'm trying to put together a simple endpoint following the Fastify with Typescript docs here:

https://www.fastify.io/docs/v3.1.x/TypeScript/

```
export default async function foo(fastify: any) {
       const MyInstance = new Foo(fastify.db);
       app.get<{ Querystring: IQueryString, Headers: IHeaders }>(
           "/foo",
           async (request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
              console.log(request.query); // *prints query object*
              const { queryObj } = request.query; // *Gives error: Object is of type 'unknown'*
              const result = await MyInstance.getFoo(queryObj);
              reply.status(200).send(result);
           }
       );
   }
```

Why do I get the error when I try to access the `request.query` object and how do I fix it?

Comment: Never annotate the types of inline callback parameters. Instead, use type inference. That is `async (request, reply) =>` instead of `async (request: FastifyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) =>`. Note: the examples in the docs you linked do this properly

Comment: That fixes the error. However, type inference doesn't seem to work on ```async(request, reply) ```. I get no implicit any on ```request``` and ```reply```.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Never say never.

Answer (score 28):

By default `FastifyRequest.query`'s type `RequestQuerystringDefault` maps to `unknown` because one cannot guess which attributes/type you'll want to set for it.

Should you have a defined type for the `query` of some request, just define that [request type](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/TypeScript/#using-generics) and use it:

```
type MyRequest = FastifyRequest<{
  Querystring: { queryObj: MyQueryObject }
}>
```

then specify it as the expected request type:

```
 async (request: MyRequest, reply: FastifyReply) => {
   const { queryObj } = request.query // Ok
 }
```

Comment: Link in the post is 404. Use [this one](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/TypeScript/#using-generics) instead.